# How to test if API call worked correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-testing-library

I have a `register` component which I want to test.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Col, Row, Container, Card,Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import { useState } from 'react';
import User from '../models/user';

let Register = () => {

    let [state,setState] = useState(new User('',''));

    let updateInput = (e) =>{
        setState({
                ...state, //state defined above in useState call. Expand the current state and then override the propoerty which target represents
                [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        })
    }

    let register = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(`registerclick: ${JSON.stringify(state)}`)

        fetch("/users",{
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(state)
            }) //move to separate funcion in separate file to make it easy to test and reuse?
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(`got response: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
                return res.json();  //return json from res
            })
            .then((data) => { //data is the json returned previously. Promise chaining
            console.log(`data after user request: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);        
            //setData(data) //override previous value of data object with value of received json object. 
            });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Container className='mt-3'>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={3}>
                        <Card className="shadow-lg">
                            <Card.Header className='p-3'>
                                 Register
                            </Card.Header>
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Form>
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                                        <Form.Control name="email" onChange={updateInput} type="text" placeholder="email" aria-label="aria-email" />
                                    </Form.Group>
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">    
                                        <Form.Control name="password" onChange={updateInput} type="password" placeholder="password" aria-label="aria-password" />
                                    </Form.Group>                                    
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">    
                                        <Button onClick={register} type="submit" name="submit-button" aria-label="aria-submit">Register Button</Button>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Form>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
            
        </>
    )
}

export default Register;
```

I am `mocking` the `fetch` call (`utils.js`).

```
module.exports = {
  mockFetch: async function (url, config) {
    switch (url) {
    case '/home': {
        return {
            ok: true,
            status: 200,
            json: async () => ({message:"welcome"}),
        }
      }
      case '/get-question': {
        //const user = await users.login(JSON.parse(config.body))
        return {
          ok: true,
          status: 200,
          json: async () => ({message:"tbd get-question"}),
        }
      }
      case '/users': {
        //const isAuthorized = user.authorize(config.headers.Authorization)
        //const isAuthorized = false
        
        return {
            ok: true,
            status: 200,
            json: async () => ({message:"result from /users mock"}),
        }
        
      }
      default: {
        throw new Error(`Unhandled request: ${url}`)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have written the following test but I don't know how to test that the `register` function was called and the response received was that from the mocked fetch

```
beforeEach(() => {
  console.log(`before each ... spying and mocking fetch`)
  jest.spyOn(window, 'fetch')
  window.fetch.mockImplementation(utils.mockFetch)
})

afterEach(() => {
  console.log(`after each ... restoring mocks`)
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
  cleanup
})
```

describe("Register form test cases - API connection", ()=>{

```
  it('Should submit the form', async () => { 
    const { getByText } = render(<Register />);
    //const mock = jest.spyOn(Register, 'register');  // call this gives error register is not a function, I suppose it is because I am not exposing register. -= Cannot spy the register property because it is not a function; undefined given instea
      
    
    fireEvent.click(getByText("Register Button")) //this works 

    //expect(getByText(/Initial/i).textContent).toBe("Initial State Changed")
    expect(1).toBe(1)
  });  
  
})
```

I see the following prints which show that the mock is working but I am not able to incorporate the validation in my test.

```
console.log
      registerclick: {"email":"","password":""}

      at register (src/components/registration.js:30:17)

    console.log
      got response: {"ok":true,"status":200}

      at src/components/registration.js:40:25

    console.log
      data after user request: {"message":"result from /users mock"}
```